# How to pass UserInfo by extra data to DBContext instance?

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, claims-based-identity

I have this scenario, I am doing a log table by following this tutorial [Entity Framework Core: History / Audit table](https://www.meziantou.net/entity-framework-core-history-audit-table.htm), but also I want to log the user who did the action. Im getting the UserId and Username by JWT Token, so I pass them by a ControllerBase which I created, where th DbContext is received by DI, and them is passed it to the repository layer.

In my DbContext I override the SaveChanges and SaveChangesAsync so I can log the modified entities.

My question is, Is it safe? I mean, this instance of the context is shared to each simultaneous API request? Or every request has it owns DbContext instance?

My DbContext looks something like this:

```cs
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration;

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    #region Audit Fields
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    #endregion

    // Customers
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    //Audit table
    public DbSet<AuditLog> Audits { get; set; }

    // Other entities...

    // Audit methods
    public override int SaveChanges(){
       ...
    }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(){
       ...
    }
}
```

My ControllerBase looks like this:

```
public class MyControllerBase<T> : ControllerBase
{
    protected MyDbContext myDbContext;
    protected AppSettings appSettings;

    public MyControllerBase(MyDbContext _myDbContext, IOptions<AppSettings> _settings){
      myDbContext= _myDbContext;
      appSettings = settings.Value;
    }

    public void SetUserInfo(){
       // Get user info from Claims by User.Identity         
       // Set the user info to the DbContext instance
       myDbContext.UserName = UserName;
       myDbContext.UserId = UserId;
    }
}
```

My DbContext in the Startup.cs file is as Transient.

Any comment/suggestion is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Transient means that every time the dependency is encountered; it creates a new service of it. The default lifetime of a DbContext is scoped. In this case, you need to be asking yourself; Why would I require an instance outside/inside the (scope) of an HTTP request?

Comment: Hello jww, thanks for commenting. Well, in this case I need an instance inside the HTTP request for logging operations too. Also I need the instance outside the request in background tasks, in this case I should create another instance of DbContext  because the DI doesn't works. But my principal question/doubt is if am I right by doing this way?.